# Sync images form Sales cloud to the marketing cloud

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to sync the images object from Sales cloud to the marketing cloud. 
Like in sales cloud there is attachment object wherein the body field content the images but the marketing cloud not allow to sync that field.

So, is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for something similar and have not found any simply way to get this. 
I have an option through pushing the files through REST API.

You can check the following link, which is the only solution I found so far.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/upload-pdf-to-content-builder-using-rest

Hope it helps